# Winning while Lord Jaraxxus as Priest

Tags: hearthstone

With the new patch, located [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/14070049/hearthstone-patch-notes-1005314-5-8-2014), winning as Lord Jaraxxus now counts as a win for the Warlock class. If I Thoughtsteal Lord Jaraxxus and win, does it count as a Priest win or a Warlock win?

Comment: That's an excellent question btw.

Comment: @Waterseas Thank you, and unfortunately, I got the answer that I didn't want to see. -_-

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/25261f/hearthstone_patch_notes_1005314/chd8wu7) a poster says they encountered that situation and it counted as a Warlock win.

Comment: Dirty Warlock's and their demons. The light shall burn them!